# How to properly program AJAX links?

Tags: nodes, 9

I have a custom module that uses AJAX. Everything works fine the way it is. I'm just wondering if it's the proper way to do it in Drupal. I'm new to Drupal 8 and 9 programming

This is a line from my code

```
$link ='<a href="/nojs/my-link/1" class="use-ajax btn btn-default">Test AJAX</a>';
```

Is this ok to do or should I be building my link? If so, why and how?

**EDIT**

I currently build non-ajax links like

```
  $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', array('node' => $record->nid));
  $title_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($record->title, $url);
  $title_link =$title_link->toRenderable();
  $title_link=render($title_link);
```

Comment: dump out $title_link->toRenderable(); then see if you can set the class  attribute and add use-ajax , if not see https://api.drupal.org/comment/63439#comment-63439
also lol you were using my comment https://api.drupal.org/comment/62725#comment-62725

Comment: So I would use ```$content = array(...```

Comment: Thanks for the comment assist before! ;)

Comment: Try this https://www.drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to add the classes I believe it can be done like so

```
$url = Url::fromRoute(
  'entity.node.canonical', 
  ['node' => $record->nid], 
  ['#attributes' => ['class' => ['btn', 'btn-default', 'use-ajax']]]
);

 $title_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl($record->title, $url);
```

At that point $title_link should be able to be rendered in the template as is!

```
// php
$variables['title_link'] = $title_link;

// twig
{{ title_link }}
```

Comment: So I gather the answer is that it's best to build links as opposed to specifying the links. And I use the build + attributes to specify AJAX and other classes.

Comment: Its subjective - but yes probably the most "Drupal way" would be to build the links as above.

Comment: Is there a reason why the "Drupal way" is better than just specifying links?

Comment: I'm probably not really qualified to answer that - but here is Drupal's page about using render arrays and Drupal's renderable elements https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/render-api/render-arrays

Comment: Thanks. I get it now, I think. It's so you can easily alter content (maybe in a separate module) as opposed to trying to alter the non-built link.